# phpMyAdmin & Varnish - “Error Cannot start session without errors”

Tags: session, nginx, phpmyadmin, varnish

So I have Ubuntu 12.04 with nginx, php5-fpm, I re-installed all many times to make phpMyAdmin work but when I install Varnish before or after, it crashes my phpMyAdmin:

Throws this error:

> phpMyAdmin - Error
>
> Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your
>   PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation
>   properly.

I already have Googled a lot, changed and set permissions etc, but still not working.

It redirects to 8080, I solved it by adding cfg, and the default `session.save_path` is set to `/var/lib/php5`, I can see some files in it (session), created with permission `0600`. Is it correct?

Also nothing in Ngnix or PHP error logs.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly, can you clarify?

Comment: here it is http://postimg.org/image/bh1atlz9n/

Comment: You should provide your varnish vcl configuration and a varnishlog trace of the error